# Dimensions of linear transformation in relation to kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am new to linear algebra, and I just wanted to doublecheck my understanding of the following:

$T: R^n \to R^m$ is a linear transformation.

True or false?

If $n>m$, then  $\operatorname{Ker}T \neq {0}$.

This statement is correct, because if $n>m$, then per definition $T$ is not injective. If $T$ is not injective, then $ \operatorname{Ker}T\neq {0}$.

Is my understanding correct?

Thank you!

Comment: *Per definition* of what?

Comment: @bernard If the original (sub)space has more dimensions than the destination one, then not all elements can be transformed in an exclusive manner. Perhaps the word "per definition" is not appropriate here, but that is the gist of what I meant.

Comment: I agree with, but it is only  an informal way of seeing things. It  is more rigourous to use the *rank-nullity formula*.

Comment: @Bernard
Thanks for the feedback: like I said, I am new to this, and I haven't studied the rank-nullity formula yet. However, I will look it up later tonight. But basically the statement is "true"?

Comment: Intuitively, it is true, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true.

The rank nullity theorem says $\operatorname{rank}T+\operatorname{nullity}T=n$.

On the other hand, $\operatorname{rank}T\le m\lt n$.  $\therefore \operatorname{nullity}T\gt0$.